# Dependent Opp Product

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I have 4 new products to add, however 3 of them are dependent on the 1 other one being sold. How can I prevent sales reps from adding the 3 dependent products without adding the "parent" product above them?

Comment: how you are maintaining the dependency? Secondly, write a trigger to prevent dependent product addition withing Parent

Comment: I'm not maintaining the dependency yet. This is a new request that I am trying to configure. I am not savvy at writing triggers. Was hoping there was a more admin-friendly solution.